# Telegram game webview shows white screen when pressing back button

Tags: html, api, webview, telegram

When user receives a chat message while playing a Telegram game and he opens this message to read a game's webview is closed. Later when he presses "Back" button he returns to game's webview but instead of the game a blank page with loading indicator is shown and nothing happens: neither the game continues nor the game's page reloads.

Is there any possibility to hook game interruptions and reload game page when user presses "back" button? Because showing white screen to user after he interrupts looks little ugly.